# simple method to assign value in CArray

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, struct, mfc

I have many data must input in CArray which element is a struct as follow

```
CArray<structCtrlField, structCtrlField> aryDefTab1CtrlField;

structCtrlField sCtrlField1 = {CTRL_FIELD_ORDER_ERROR, _T(CTRL_FIELD_NAME_ERROR),
    _T(CTRL_FIELD_CODE_ERROR), 0};
theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField.Add(sCtrlField1);
structCtrlField sCtrlField2 = {CTRL_FIELD_ORDER_ACTIVE, _T(CTRL_FIELD_NAME_ACTIVE),
    _T(CTRL_FIELD_CODE_ACTIVE), 0};
theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField.Add(sCtrlField2);
```

I try to

```
theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField[0] =  {CTRL_FIELD_ORDER_ERROR, _T(CTRL_FIELD_NAME_ERROR),
    _T(CTRL_FIELD_CODE_ERROR), 0};
theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField[2] =  {CTRL_FIELD_ORDER_ACTIVE, _T(CTRL_FIELD_NAME_ACTIVE),
    _T(CTRL_FIELD_CODE_ACTIVE), 0};
```

But the compiler can't run it...

How to define the aryDefTab1CtrlField?

Comment: Add a `Set(...)` method to `structCtrlField` so that you can set all the parameters in one go.

Comment: can you give me a example? THX

Comment: Remember that you can obtain a pointer to your data: theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField.GetData(). I would follow @RogerRowland solution by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the declaration of `structCtrlField`, but I'm assuming it's something like this (you'll get the idea anyway) :

```
struct structCtrlField
{
    CString szOne;
    CString szTwo;
    CString szThree;
    int nNum;
};
```

Then add a member function to the struct to allow you to set the fields:

```
struct structCtrlField
{
    CString szOne;
    CString szTwo;
    CString szThree;
    int nNum;

    void Set(LPCTSTR sz1, LPCTSTR sz2, LPCTSTR sz3, int n1)
    {
        // set members
        szOne = sz1;
        szTwo = sz2;
        szThree = sz3;
        nNum = n1;
    }
};
```

Then, using your example code, you can set new values like so:

```
theApp.aryDefTab1CtrlField[0].Set(CTRL_FIELD_ORDER_ERROR, 
                                  _T(CTRL_FIELD_NAME_ERROR),
                                  _T(CTRL_FIELD_CODE_ERROR), 
                                  0);
```